# Only show line items containing specific strings in liquid

Tags: liquid

I have the following table:

```
<table>
 <tbody>

    {% for lineItem in lineItems %}
    
      {% assign cleanDesc = lineItem.description | strip %}

      <tr class="{% cycle "bg-white", "bg-gray-100" %}">
  
        <td class="text-left">{{lineItem.description}}</td>
        <td class="text-left">
            {% if cleanDesc == "VAT" %}
            Standard Rate
            {% elsif cleanDesc == "VAT Gear exempt"%}
            25% Zero Rate, 75% Standard Rate
            {% else %}
            {% endif %}
        </td>
        <td class="text-right">£{{lineItem.tax_only_cost | with_delimiter, precision: 2}} </td>
      </tr>
    {% endfor %}
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I wish to only display in this table items with lineItem.description == "VAT" or "VAT Gear exempt".

I can get this to work for "VAT", but cannot get it to work for "VAT Gear exempt".

Please could you advise how I can not allow `<tr>` rows to be created for any line items, except for descriptions "VAT" and "VAT Gear exempt".

Comment: Did you test a display of cleanDesc var to check if "VAT Gear exempt" exists (strip filter might have an impact)?

Answer (score 0):

Dont strip description, just use "contains" operator like:

```
{% if lineItem.description contains "VAT" or if lineItem.description contains "VAT Gear exento" %}

   <!-- Code if lineItem.Description contains these words -->

{% endif%}
```